# Bower error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: angularjs, bower

I have built an application using AngularJS and an ionic template. The application is working fine in my browser but when running `cordova build android` I create the `apk` I have problems. In the specific, I can create the `apk` but once execute I have the following error for the packages:

`file:///android_asset/www/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/css/angular-bootstrap-calendar.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I understand that those files are not found but I cannot understand why.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
the problem was that using gulp only part of the files were copied. I solved just doing an `cp -r app/* www` I hope this can help someone in the future.

Thanks